# I get an extra term when I try to derive $\nabla\!\!\!\!/\ ^2=\nabla_\mu \nabla^\mu+\frac{1}{4}[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]F_{\mu\nu}$

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, dirac-equation

The equation in the title can be found in [Nakahara's book](https://www.routledge.com/Geometry-Topology-and-Physics/Nakahara/p/book/9780750306065), page 507 (chapter 13, Anomalies in Gauge Field Theories) and in [Fujikawa's book](https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198529132.001.0001), pages 69 and 78 (chapter 5, The Jacobian in Path Integrals and
Quantum Anomalies). However, when I try to derive this equation, using the trick $BA=\frac{1}{2}\{B,A\}+\frac{1}{2}[B,A]$, I get an extra term:
\begin{align*}
    &(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu)(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu)=\frac{1}{2}\big(\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}+[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]\big)\frac{1}{2}\big(\{\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu\}+[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]\big)&\\
    &=\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}\{\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu\}+\frac{1}{4}\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]}_{\frac{1}{2}\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu=\eta^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu=\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu}+\frac{1}{4}[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]\{\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu\}+\frac{1}{4}[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]\underbrace{[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu]}_{=F_{\mu\nu}}&\\
    &=\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu+\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}[\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}]\{\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu\}}_{\text{extra term}}+\frac{1}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]F_{\mu\nu}&
\end{align*}

Is the "extra term" zero for some reason or is $\nabla^\mu$ defined in a different way (I assumed $\nabla^\mu=\eta^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\nu$)?

Comment: If I am not mistaken $[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]$ is an antisymmetric tensor contracted with a symmetric tensor $\{\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu\}$ and therefore yields 0.

Comment: @krabbypatty You are right, thank you! I'm drafting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P\to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle with a representation $\rho\colon G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$.

The "extra term" is the endomorphism $O\colon C^{\infty}(M,\Delta\otimes V)\to C^{\infty}(M,\Delta\otimes V)$ defined by
\begin{equation}
O(\psi)=[\gamma^k,\gamma^l]\cdot\{\nabla_k,\nabla_l\}(\psi)=\sum_{k,l}[\gamma^k,\gamma^l]\cdot\{\nabla_k,\nabla_l\}(\psi).
\end{equation}
We prove $O=-O$ (which is equivalent to $O=0$):

Since $[A,B]=-[B,A]$ and $\{A,B\}=\{B,A\}$,
\begin{equation}
O(\psi)=[\gamma^k,\gamma^l]\cdot\{\nabla_k,\nabla_l\}(\psi)=-[\gamma^l,\gamma^k]\cdot\{\nabla_l,\nabla_k\}(\psi)=-O(\psi)
\end{equation}
for all $\psi\in C^{\infty}(M,\Delta\otimes V)$.

(To be precise, we would have to replace $\gamma^\mu$ by $\gamma^\mu\otimes 1$.)

Comment: Can you explain what this object $\Delta \otimes V$ represents?

Comment: @DanielC I'm glad you ask this (I was afraid to add too much information). I learnt gauge theory with the help of [Hamilton's book](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-68439-0). In chapter 5.9, he defines the covariant derivative in a very general setting: Principal $G$-bundle $P\to M$ + a representation $\rho\colon G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ + a connection 1-form $A\in\Omega^1(M)\otimes g$. If $M$ is endowed with a spin structure $S$

Comment: (that's a principal $\mathrm{Spin}$-bundle with a representation $\kappa\colon\mathrm{Spin}\to\mathrm{GL}(\Delta)$, where $\Delta$ is the complex vector space of spinors, see chapter 6.9). We can form the fiber product $P\times S$ of $P$ and $S$ (remark 6.12.7), which is a principal $G\times\mathrm{Spin}$-bundle. Using $\rho$ and $\kappa$, we can construct a representation $G\times\mathrm{Spin}\to\mathrm{GL}(\Delta\times V)$ and obtain an associated vector bundle $E$.

Comment: The Dirac operator is an endomorphism $D\colon\Gamma(M,E)\to\Gamma(M,E)$ and if $\Psi\in\Gamma(M,E)$ and $s\in\Gamma(U,P\times S)$ is a local gauge, there is (exactly one) $\psi\in C^{\infty}(M,\Delta\otimes V)$ s.t. $\Psi|_U=[s,\psi]$ and $D\Psi|_U=[s,D\psi]$, where $D$ is the dirac operator and $D\psi$ is given by the local formula known to physicists (chapter 6.11). In the equation from the title, the spin connection term was dropped from the covariant derivative (that is, I considered a "simplified" version of the dirac operator).